# co-orninates of glutsolidsphere in opengl

Tags: opengl, glut

```
glutSolidSphere(GLdouble radius,
                     GLint slices, GLint stacks);
```

here specifies only radius,slices and stacks, not specifying where to draw !! means the co-ordinates specified where? Is it do only with gltranslatef() ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, glutSolidSphere always draws with the center at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, push your matrix, translate it by glTranslate, draw your sphere, pop your matrix.